# Display django field choices in a particular order

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am using django models and one of the charfields has a list of choices like

```
class Ster(models.Model):
    STER_PRODUCTS_CATEGORY = [
        ('Steam', 'Steam'),
        ('ETO', 'ETO'),
        ('Plasma', 'Plasma'),
        ('LTSF', 'LTSF'),
        ('Heat', 'Heat')
    ]
    ster_prod_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ster_prod_category = models.CharField(
        max_length=100, choices=STER_PRODUCTS_CATEGORY, default='None')
```

Whenever I add an item to any of the category, that particular category is shown first on the webpage. 
For ex, if i add an item to the category Heat, that category is displayed first. 
I am looping through the list. My **views.py** function looks like this

```
ster_catprods = Ster.objects.values('ster_prod_category', 'id')
ster_cats = {ster_item['ster_prod_category']
                 for ster_item in ster_catprods}
for ster_cat in ster_cats:
        ster_prod = Ster.objects.filter(ster_prod_category=ster_cat)
        m = len(ster_prod)
        mSlides = m // 4 + ceil((m / 4) - (m // 4))
        ster_prods.append([ster_prod, range(1, mSlides), mSlides])
```

My **HTML Template** snippet is like this

```
<section class="container">
    <h4 style="margin: 1em auto">1.STER</h4>
    <div class="row">
        {% for p,range,mSlides in ster_prods %}
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 col-lg-4 col-xl-4" data-aos="zoom-in-up" style="margin: 1em auto">
            <h4 class="category-title my-4">{{p.0.ster_prod_category | safe}}</h4>
            {% for i in p %}
            <h6 class="product_title">{{i.ster_prod_name | safe }}</h6></a>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</section>
```

how do i get to display the categories in a **particular order** like the way i want? 
**The order I want:**
Steam
ETO
Plasma
LTSF
Heat

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `.objects.values` as it contacts the database. You can loop for the list `Ster.STER_PRODUCTS_CATEGORY` which will keep the order.

Comment: doing so gives me the error
`TypeError: 'list' object is not callable`
@mkalioby

Comment: On which line??

Comment: if i replace .objects.values to Ster.STER_PRODUCTS_CATEGORY, its showing the above error. @mkalioboy